# Android custom Intent chooser to list Activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to make a custom Intent chooser for the `ACTION_SEND`

```
PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    .setType("application/octet-stream");

List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);
Collections.sort(resInfo, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
   String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
   Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
      .setType("application/octet-stream")
      .setPackage(packageName);
   targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
}
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Title");
chooserIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

the problem is that for applications that have multiple activities with the same action (Like ES File Explorer), it is listed multiple times as "Android System" *Like in Figure 1*. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxy2A.jpg

and then if selected it gives you the standard Intent chooser associated with that application *Like in Figure 2*.

**The Question**: how can I implement a custom Intent chooser like the build-in one, where each Activity is listed together.
*like in Figure 3*.

Comment: `like the build-in one`. Build in what/which?

Comment: Tried on five devices. Only one displayed "Android-system" twice. All others had one ES File Explorer icon. What happens if more apps show twice? You know another one?

Comment: @greenapps by `build-in one` I mean the build-in Activity chooser when you choose an Activity which has multiple apps that can handle it, see figure 3 at http://goo.gl/dGbwn0 ,  the android build emulator nexus one shows up "Android-system",

Comment: Ok. I found a partial solution but would like to test it with another app that displays this behaviour. I asked you to mention another app but you did not.

Comment: I don't have another app, but I guess that every app which will Implement the same `Action` more than one time in different `Activity`, will have the same results

Answer (score 1):

Found something to get rid of the "Android-system" text and now its displaying "ES File Explorer" instead. And an es file explorer icon. I had added these log statements:

```
Log.d(TAG, packageName );
Log.d(TAG, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name );
```

and the result for ES File Explores was:

```
 com.estrongs.android.pop
 com.estrongs.android.pop.app.ESFileSharingActivity
 com.estrongs.android.pop
 com.estrongs.android.pop.app.SaveToESActivity
```

then i added following statement in the loop:

```
 targetedShareIntent.setClassName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
```

So now you will see twice ES File Explorer. But unlucky twice the same info. And the same icon.

Think you should mail the guys of es file explorer a link to this post. They are helpfull. They will be interested.